# VB.NET Query Linq for get all elements node

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I'm try to understandin Linq to XML and I've this file XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Headers  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/GridLayerSchema.xsd">
  <Header>
   <Name>Layer0</Name>
    <Fields FieldID="FieldID0" FieldName="FieldNameAll" FieldPosition="0" FieldPositionStart="0" FieldLenght="254" FieldEnable="true" />
   </Header>
  <Header>
   <Name>Layer1</Name>
   <Fields FieldID="FieldID0" FieldName="JetPosition" FieldPosition="0" FieldPositionStart="0" FieldLenght="14" FieldEnable="true" />
   <Fields FieldID="FieldID1" FieldName="Owner" FieldPosition="1" FieldPositionStart="14" FieldLenght="14" FieldEnable="true" />
   <Fields FieldID="FieldID2" FieldName="Item" FieldPosition="2" FieldPositionStart="28" FieldLenght="3" FieldEnable="true" />
  </Header>
</Headers>
```

I'll try to take all elements with a linq query for making a VB.net class, somethink like this:

```
 Class Field:
  Public Class Field
  Public Property FieldID1 As String
  Public Property FieldName As String
  Public Property FieldPosition As Integer
  Public Property FieldPositionStart As Integer
  Public Property FieldLenght As Integer
  Public Property FieldEnable As Boolean
End Class
```

Then the Header class:

```
Public Class Header : Inherits Field
  Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

In this one I'va a function for making a Headers collection:

```
Public Shared Function HeadersLoader() As Headers
    Dim HeadersCollection As New Headers
    Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/GridLayerSchema.xsd"
    Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Layers\Headers.xml")

     Dim HeadersQuery = From Header In xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "Header")
                       Select Header
    For Each e In HeadersQuery
        Dim _mHeader As New Header
        With _mHeader
            .Name = e.Value.ToString
        End With
        HeadersCollection.Add(_mHeader)
    Next
    Return HeadersCollection
   End Function
```

Now I've two questions:

- Why I've the Header's name in Value property and not in Name property (in name property I've all the namespace  and the header tag, but not the name: {http://tempuri.org/GridLayerSchema.xsd}Header )
- How can I read all fields of the current Header?I need a nested query? I'll thought, with my query, to find all but seems not so, I can read only the first node.

Comment: What do you mean by "in Value property"? If you mean "in the XElement's Value property", it's because the header name *is* the value of the `<Name>` element, whereas the *name* of the `<Name>` element is "Name" (with an appropriate namespace). Your question isn't terribly clear at the moment.

Comment: I'm pretty new in XML and I'm tring to make an easy code for understanding the LINQ statements. In the XML file I've the <Name> tag so I want to read this one. if you tell me the <Name> tag is the property value, well, if not as I read the tag <Name>?

Comment: Okay, I think I know where you're going wrong now... I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <Headers xmlns="http://tempuri.org/GridLayerSchema.xsd">
                  <Header>
                      <Name>Layer0</Name>
                      <Fields FieldID="FieldID0" FieldName="FieldNameAll" FieldPosition="0" FieldPositionStart="0" FieldLenght="254" FieldEnable="true"/>
                  </Header>
                  <Header>
                      <Name>Layer1</Name>
                      <Fields FieldID="FieldID0" FieldName="JetPosition" FieldPosition="0" FieldPositionStart="0" FieldLenght="14" FieldEnable="true"/>
                      <Fields FieldID="FieldID1" FieldName="Owner" FieldPosition="1" FieldPositionStart="14" FieldLenght="14" FieldEnable="true"/>
                      <Fields FieldID="FieldID2" FieldName="Item" FieldPosition="2" FieldPositionStart="28" FieldLenght="3" FieldEnable="true"/>
                  </Header>
              </Headers>

    Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/GridLayerSchema.xsd"

    Dim query = (From elmHeader In xml.Root.Elements(ns + "Header")
          Select New Header With {
             .Name = CStr(elmHeader.Element(ns + "Name")),
             .Fields = (From elmField In elmHeader.Elements(ns + "Fields")
                       Select New Field With {
                             .FieldID1 = CStr(elmField.Attribute("FieldID")),
                             .FieldName = CStr(elmField.Attribute("FieldName")),
                             .FieldPosition = CInt(elmField.Attribute("FieldPosition")),
                             .FieldPositionStart = CInt(elmField.Attribute("FieldPositionStart")),
                             .FieldLenght = CInt(elmField.Attribute("FieldLenght")),
                             .FieldEnable = CBool(elmField.Attribute("FieldEnable"))
                           }).ToList()
             }).ToList()
End Sub

Public Class Field
    Public Property FieldID1 As String
    Public Property FieldName As String
    Public Property FieldPosition As Integer
    Public Property FieldPositionStart As Integer
    Public Property FieldLenght As Integer
    Public Property FieldEnable As Boolean
End Class

Public Class Header : Inherits Field 'I think you can drop this inherits but that's up to you
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Fields As IEnumerable(Of Field)
End Class
```

... BTW, if you add an Imports at the top of your file you can clean up the query more with XML literals.

```
Imports <xmlns:ns="http://tempuri.org/GridLayerSchema.xsd">
```

...

```
Dim query = From elmHeader In xml.Root.<ns:Header>
            Select New Header With {
                    .Name = elmHeader.<ns:Name>.First(),
                    .Fields = From elmField In elmHeader.<ns:Fields>
                            Select New Field With {
                                    .FieldID1 = elmField.@FieldID,
                                    .FieldName = elmField.@FieldName,
                                    .FieldPosition = elmField.@FieldPosition,
                                    .FieldPositionStart = elmField.@FieldPositionStart,
                                    .FieldLenght = elmField.@FieldLenght,
                                    .FieldEnable = elmField.@FieldEnable
                                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I had thought I need to make two queries. Now I have to understand haw I can read the field propeties for adding in my HeadersCollection..

Answer (score 1):

You're being confused by the fact that the `Value` property on `XElement` will concatenate all the text nodes within an element, including within descendants. That *happens* to be getting the text value of the `Name` child element, because that's the only element you've got with any text. It would be better to write:

```
With _mHeader
    .Name = e.Element(ns + "Name").Value
```

That way you're explicitly asking for the text within the `<Name>` child element.

Now your class design is a bit messed up because you're saying that a header *is* a field, rather than that it *has* a list of fields. I think you should have something like:

```
Public Class Header
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Fields As List(Of Field)
End Class
```

(possibly with some initialization). I would then change your LINQ query to create the instances of `Header` within the `Select` clause. I'm not going to attempt the VB, but in C# I'd have something like:

```
var headers = xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "Header")
                  .Select(header => new Header
                  {
                      Name = header.Element("Name").Value,
                      Fields = header.Elements("Fields")
                                     .Select(field => new Field
                                     {
                                         FieldID1 = field.Element("FieldID)".Value,
                                         // etc
                                     })
                                     .ToList();
                  });
```

You might want to add static `FromXElement` methods to `Header` and `Field` (where `Header.FromXElement` would use `Field.FromXElement`) to make this all a bit simpler.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the query. Maybe in C# LINQ code you can have a .Select, but in VB.net  I can't find nothing similar. Maybe I've to make two querys?

Comment: @GianfrancoVrech: No, that's just a call to the extension method. It should be fine - it's just not using a query expression as there wouldn't be much point. I suggest you read a good VB LINQ tutorial as that should cover both syntaxes.